# How to capture characters and newlines from serial and print to file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to capture data coming across a serial in a python script.  The stream ends with a '#' and the stream can contain letters, numbers, many other special characters and new lines.  I'd like to capture all characters and place them in a file when it finishes.  I'm not sure, however, if my re is correct.  Is

`re.match("[A-Za-z0-9,.$:<>&*=-]", char, re.DOTALL)`

going to capture all letters, numbers, and `,.$:<>&*=-` characters as well as newlines?  Can I simply add each char as it comes across, place it in a list and then later write the list t a file like so:

```
while 1:
   # must handle 'exceptions' - IE blank data....
   try:
      if s.inWaiting():
         val = s.read(s.inWaiting())
         for char in val:
            if re.match("[A-Za-z0-9,.$:<>&=-]", char, re.DOTALL):
               chunk += char
               print char

            # handle end of stream
            #if char is '#':
            if re.match("#", char):
               f = open('./report', 'w')
               f.write(chunk)
               sys.exit()
```

Currently it is grabbing all I expect but it does not appear to be grabbing the new lines as the resulting file does not contain any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're using `re.DOTALL`, your regex doesn't actually use the dot operator. Changing line 7 to the following should work as you expect:

```
if re.match("[A-Za-z0-9,.$:<>&=-]|\n", char):
```

Works for both *nix based, and PC based newline encodings, as `\r` will simply be ignored by the regex.